# Php Array push with key

Tags: php, arrays, array-push

Here is what I want  to output:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [restriction_type_code] => CALORICONTROL
            [restriction_detail_code] => 3000CAL
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [restriction_type_code] => GLUTENFREE
            [restriction_detail_code] => NR
        )

)
```

and my actual code looks like this:

[image]

restriction : [image]

```
foreach ($restriction as   $value) 
                {
                    $itemSplit =  explode("||", $value);
                    $itemSplit1 = explode("|", $itemSplit[0]);
                    $itemSplit2 = explode("|", $itemSplit[0]); 

                    $arrOrderDiet['restriction_type_code'][] = $itemSplit1 //CALORICONTROL;
                    $arrOrderDiet['restriction_detail_code'][] = $itemSplit2//3000CAL;

                }
```

Im trying all the possibilities but I think i ran out of solutions.

Comment: Ok post your source pls

Comment: We don't know what your data looks like mate

Comment: The output array should be like the one i posted on the top.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this

```
foreach ($restriction as   $value) 
                {
                    $itemSplit =  explode("||", $value);
                    $itemSplit1 = explode("|", $itemSplit[0]);
                    $itemSplit2 = explode("|", $itemSplit[1]); 

                    $arrOrderDiet[] = array('restriction_type_code' => $itemSplit1, 'restriction_detail_code' => $itemSplit2);

                }
```

**Edit:**

```
foreach ($restriction as   $value) 
                    {
                        $itemSplit =  explode("||", $value);
                        $itemSplit1 = explode("|", $itemSplit[0]);
                        $itemSplit2 = explode("|", $itemSplit[1]); 

                        $arrOrderDiet[] = array('restriction_type_code' => $itemSplit1[0], 'restriction_detail_code' => $itemSplit2[2]);

                    }
```

Comment: it returns this :

[0] => Array
        (
            [restriction_type_code] => Array
                (
                    [0] => CALORICONTROL
                    [1] => Calorie controlled
                )

            [restriction_detail_code] => Array
                (
                    [0] => CALORICONTROL
                    [1] => Calorie controlled
                )

        )

Comment: still not the answer I want to be. ~sigh

Comment: Don't you think you posted a bit too early considering you have no idea what the data actually looks like?

Comment: Yep... Can you copy `print_r($itemSplit1)` and `print_r($itemSplit2)` output?

Comment: You updated with the output of `$restrictions`, i updated my answer anyways

Answer (score 0):

Why do you have both indices the same in:

```
$itemSplit1 = explode("|", $itemSplit[0]);
$itemSplit2 = explode("|", $itemSplit[0]);
```

Shouldn't it be like this:

```
$itemSplit1 = explode("|", $itemSplit[0]);
$itemSplit2 = explode("|", $itemSplit[1]);
```

Plus:

```
$tmp['restriction_type_code'] = $itemSplit1[0];
$tmp['restriction_detail_code'] = $itemSplit2[0];
$arrOrderDiet[] = $tmp;
```